# How can I pull back an email that has already been sent?

Tags: email, email-client

I sent a sensitive email with an attachment to the wrong email address. Is there a way to invalidate (or pull back) this email and the attachment remotely? The email was sent out via the aol.com email agent.

I know there is a way to invalidate an attachment sent along with the email, but I am  not sure about the email itself.

Comment: “I know there is a way to invalidate an attachment sent along with the email,” – There isn’t. Only if the attachment were encrypted and could only be decrypted using an online service would such a thing be feasible.

Comment: I got an email in my yahoo account from a company's domain that had an attachment (sensitive doc). Obviously, that email was not intended for me. Later, that company was able to make that attachment empty on my end. Any idea on how this attachment was emptied?

Comment: It was likely not an attachment, but a link.

Comment: Unsending messages is currently available only in the paid AOL Desktop Gold software. You cannot unsend an email from the online AOL Mail or from the AOL mobile app. Kindly refer the following article: [How to Unsend an Email in AOL](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-unsend-an-email-in-aol-1170975)

Comment: @Sunny Only between AOL users. There is no way to unsend a normal email.

Comment: @Sunny Not true. It can also be done with Microsoft Exchange, under certain specific conditions. I've seen quite a few emails get pulled that way, where I hadn't opened them before they were pulled. It's called "Message Recall".

Comment: The recipient could even download the email, store it on a drive, disconnect from the Internet, and load it up in any email client... once it's sent it's a file on someone else's drive. Sorry. P.S. Teaching online has led to many unusual technical circumstances. Not long ago I had a student submit a .eml file to a written assignment. Curious, I downloaded it and opened it in Thunderbird. Thankfully it was able to open it. The file contained an email from the student to himself, to which he had attached his submission as a Word document. I have no idea how he managed to do this by mistake.

Comment: @DanielB Just a nitpick, but there do exist attachments which load remote content when you open them. These could be "invalidated" by removing the remote content before the recipient has opened the attachment. But I doubt that covers the OP's case.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

#### Is there a way to invalidate (or pull back) this email and the attachment remotely?

Normally no.

However, some email services have a short window when you can "recall" mail:

- gmail - 30 seconds maximum - during which you can cancel sending email(s) (so it's not a true "recall")
- outlook - you can un-send email in Outlook only if that email is internal (both you and your recipient have an Office 365 or Microsoft Exchange email account in the same organization) and it hasn’t been viewed yet.
- yahoo - not possible
- AOL Gold (and AOL Mail in general) no longer offer this feature

Answer (score 35):

In a practical way, no.

The situation is analog to regular mail. Once you drop a letter in the mailbox, it is pretty much gone. Now, not discussing the legal aspect, in principle you could remove the letter from the mailbox until the time the truck comes to pick it up. After that, you could somehow stop the truck, and the same with different parts of the delivery process. But it would require, even in the best of cases, good timing and a little persuassion. Lastly you could also get the letter from your recipients mailbox before they open it.

In the electronic case, the situation is similar. After you send an email it usually passes from server to server (usually at least two), and it stays at the destination server until the client checks their email. In principle, again, you could stop the process at any time by deleting the file from the corresponding server before it is sent to the next one. Thing is, most of the time this happens fairly quickly (seconds, although in some cases it could be hours and sometimes even more in the past). And in general you don't have access to any of the servers involved.

Summary: technically possible, during a usually short window; basically impossible in practice.

Comment: But in almost all cases, you don't have the technical ability to get to the servers in time to stop the email from being sent onwards.  Like chasing the mail truck: if the driver goes faster than you can run, you can't stop it.  Really the only remotely feasible method would be to hack into the recipient's email account, and delete the message before it's read.

Comment: "_it usually bounces between a few (at least two) servers_" I should hope it doesn't bounce between servers as this implies going back and forth between them, not just one way. It's a minimum of _one_ server when you consider that you could be emailing someone on the same system that you use

Comment: @roaima I don't think that's implied at all. A pinball can bounce off many obstacles in the pinball machine; that doesn't require it to touch any of them more than once.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, I think, roaima wanted to highlight that when it comes to e-mail, the term "to bounce" has special meaning: for an e-mail server which is sent a message, to bounce it is an action opposite to receiving it (for delivery of forwarding further). Hence when once says "a message bounced" means some MTA in the chain of transfer rejected to handle the message and sent back another one describing the details of that mishap.

Comment: @kostix Absolutely, that's a common case of bouncing. But it's also an example of a misuse of a term :P

Comment: @Asteroids With Wings: The language problem isn't with bounce, it's with between.  Like the pinball: it generally bounces from bumper to bumper on its way down the board, but seldom actually between any two.

Comment: @jamesqf I'll give you that!

Comment: I edited the answer and removed the word bounce.

Answer (score 15):

> I know there is a way to invalidate an attachment sent along with the email, but not sure about the email itself.

This, also isn't true. Attachments are just encoded in a way that allows the email system to transfer them, but they are carried within the same message. This would be different if you don't actually attach the file, but instead upload the file to some separate server and only send a link. This could be as simple as an HTTP server and an URL to the file, or it could be something done by a more sophisticated document control system.

Answer (score 10):

#### How to pull back an email that has already been sent?

After it was sent, probably in no way, **but**

**the administrator of the receiving server** (who manages the mailbox of the e-mail address of the wrong recipient), **could still physically delete the mail from the server before it is accessed.** It is a question of time and opportunity.

**Time.** This is obviously useful as long as it has not yet been downloaded. After that, he can still delete the server copy, but he cannot delete the downloaded one(s).
**Opportunity.** The administrator of the receiving server may have not the legal right to do it. Or even the possibility to act in time.

However, if it is an email within the company and an internal server is used, an email to and a quick phone call to the mail administrator could still be sufficient (when the company policies allow it).

---

#### Safe procedures at work

Instead, you may need to use **in advance** *safe* procedures at work, especially dealing with sensitive content.

- Use **encryption** , e.g. PGP,  for the attachment with the public key given by the receiver. If you sent the attachement to the wrong people they will not be able to read. Using the key given by the right receiver you doublecheck your work.
- Put **attachments as links to a (local) cloud copy** instead of the file. It is easy and quick in this case to delete, rename, change the permission to the file so that the link included in the mail become broken.
- Use **encryption** and send the password via a different communication way. (Once again doublechecking).

---

#### Some words more (tl;dr)

An email written on your computer is sent from your client (outlook, your web browser ...) to a *sending* mail server which processes the request by sending it to a *receiving* server. Received mail is here archived with the attachment in the final recipient area, waiting for the user to download it. Everything happens in a few moments.

You can act in each step:

- Before it exits from the sending server.
  Some clients and some provider online pages (gmail ...) have a *grace time*: they allow you to **defer the sending time** by a few seconds (usually up to 30): this is a compromise between immediacy shipment and the time to reconsider/realize that an attachment is missing, or there has been an inadvertent sending. You have read an **undo** action, but the mail has not actually been sent yet.
- After it is received but not delivered to the final recipient.
  Some services (Microsoft, ...) allow to pull back a mail, **within a corporate network**; it does not always work when the deletion occurs after synchronization by a client set to make local copies and delete only at the explicit request of the user.
  If you can contact and convince the administrator of the receiving email address in time, they can delete the mail not yet downloaded.

Comment: Gmail isn't really a true client, but that reminds me of something similar that can be done in a real mail client. Real mail clients fully support working offline and have an Outbox for sending mail. Occasionally, my connection to the server will stop working for a few minutes so messages will stay in my Outbox until that works again, but I could also manually suspend outgoing mail and choose to send my messages at a specific point. Effectively, the Gmail feature keeps the message in the outbox for 30 seconds, but in a mail client you can disable automatic sending and get the same "feature".

Comment: @InterLinked Rather than ranting about GMail not being a True Scotsman, you could just have said "in many mail clients". There have probably been hundreds of mail clients over the years, some of which worked that way and had those options, and some which didn't; I don't think defining the term "mail client" to only include those that do is particularly helpful.

Comment: @IMSoP Gmail isn't a real mail client. That's just the reality. Neither is Yahoo, neither is Outlook.com, etc. Outlook, Thunderbird, MailNews, those are mail clients. Gmail is a webmail interface. I have Gmail accounts but I never log in to mail.google.com. Mail clients are programs that run locally, most of which has a number of basic features that virtually no webmail service (including Gmail) has.

Comment: Gmail webmail app **is** a mail client, that connects to Google mail servers. It just happens that the client is running on Google servers as well and you access it via a web browser. It is a similar situation as when you access your mail the "old-fashioned" way, by ssh-ing into the server and using a console mode mail client that runs on the server, like mutt or pine (I still prefer to do exactly this instead of using a local mail client).

Comment: @InterLinked, meh, I would wager gmail also has features some "real" mail clients don't have. In any case, a web client that under the hood accesses a mailbox via e.g. IMAP would still be a mail client just in the way a dedicated binary on your machine that accesses it via IMAP. no?

Comment: As for the note of using encryption in the post, that of course relies on your mail client (whatever it is) having you choose the right key separately from choosing the right recipient. That would seem quite unwieldy, and a bad UI. :|

Comment: @ilkkachu  Not necessarily. Maybe I have not fully expressed it. In some workplaces it is expressly required to encrypt attachments with programs separate from the mail clients, for security reasons (basically if the security of the client is compromised, that of the content is not yet ...)

Comment: @Hastur, yes, I was looking at this from the point of view where it pays off to make encryption easy so people will actually use it... That one would be a different case, though I do wonder how safe the unencrypted copies of the attachments would be if someone were to find an arbitrary code execution vulnerability in the email client.

Comment: @ilkkachu what "features"? Very standard things, like proper inline replies and attachment management, are rarely or not supported at all by pretty much any webmail client. (The full Outlook chokes on replies as well though). Configuration in general is quite limited to the "features" they want available. I can see what you're saying, though maybe I'd call it a "webmail" client. At the very least, it's not a "full" mail client. Some webmail services like Outlook.com do let you manage other accounts using IMAP or POP, but it's still a far cry from a real/full client.

Answer (score 8):

Simply put, you cannot.

Send a follow-up email requesting that the receiver delete the previous communication as it is private information sent in error.

It will be nice if they respond but do not demand a response from this person.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is possible only in Microsoft Exchange environment - when both you and the recipient are using Microsoft Exchange and Microsoft Outlook for your mail. There is a function in MS Outlook called "Message Recall" that allows to do this, but only under a condition that the recipient hasn't viewed the message yet.

In other cases, there is no possibility to withdraw an already sent email.

Comment: This is a correct answer, but you have only repeated [an answer that has been here for two days.](https://superuser.com/a/1616450/220919). Try to avoid giving redundant answers..

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the general sentiments above that it's not reliably possible any more.

I notice many answers talk about Microsoft Exchange server and the "message recall" option, with the caveat that it only works if the recipient hasn't viewed the message yet. I thought I would add a point of clarification based on my experiences before we moved to Office 365.

In my experience that caveat is only true if the user doesn't also use ActiveSync. Back in the day when people only opened Exchange emails in their Outlook desktop client the recall feature would work as advertised for any user who had yet to open the email in Outlook. As more and more staff started syncing their smart phones with Exchange I noticed that recall worked less and less.

It turned out that because ActiveSync was syncing the message to their phone, Exchange seemed to count that as reading the email even though the user might not have opened it in Outlook. It didn't appear to need to be read on the phone either, just synced.

Answer (score -2):

if you are using office 365 you can
[image]

use this option but only inside the organization

Comment: Just posting a (Hebrew) screenshot is not going to help many here.